# Как отправить файл на веб сервер с помощью powershell. Принимаю php скриптом

Tags: php, powershell

Нужно отправить файл на удаленный веб сервер. 
Пытаюсь использовать такой код powershell  на клиенте:

```
$boundary = [guid]::NewGuid().ToString()
$file = "D:\test\test.xml"
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri http://url.url/catcher.php -ContentType "multipart/form-data; boundary=$boundary" -Body [byte]$file
```

код на сервере:

```
<?php

$uploaddir = './files/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir.basename($_FILES['uploadfile']['name']);


if (copy($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)){
                echo "<h3>Done!</h3>";
}
    else { 
                echo "<h3>Error!</h3>"; 
                exit; 
}

?>
```

Лог выдает:

```
[Sun Jul 03 00:57:16.687956 2016] [:error] [pid 10870] [client...] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: uploadfile in /.../catcher.php on line 5
[Sun Jul 03 00:57:16.739238 2016] [:error] [pid 10870] [client...] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: uploadfile in /.../catcher.php on line 9
[Sun Jul 03 00:57:16.756561 2016] [:error] [pid 10870] [client...] PHP Warning:  copy(): Filename cannot be empty in /.../catcher.php on line 9
```

То ли PS не отправляет, то ли у php проблемы с получением имени файла...

Comment: Речь идет о powershell.

Comment: Очень интересно, что вы пытаетесь получить этой конструкцией: `[byte]$file`? Подсказка: она не работает и работать не должна.

Comment: Вы посылаете на сервер содержимое формы как параметры, а php код пытается принять файл.
-OUtFile ?